# Getting AccessDenied when enumerating BLE characteristics

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to convert a working UWP app to a WPF one using .NET 6 with Target framework monikers.
I can scan BLE devices with no issues and connect to them, however I get an AccessDenied status at the **next GetCharacteristicsAsync's call**

I have checked characteristics properties and they all have the flag corresponding to the operation I am doing.

My OS version is 1943 and my target version is net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0

I have tried using BLuetoothCacheMode.Cached and Uncached: same result.

Edit:I have tried to call `RequestAccessAsync` and it does not seem to do anything. However this same method returns Allowed.

Here is a piece of code I use, it is inpired by the microsoft docs.

```cs
public async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync(string serviceUuid, string characteristicUuid)
        {
            using var bluetoothLEDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(_device.DeviceId);

            GattDeviceServicesResult result1 = await bluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);

            if (result1.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                foreach (var service in result1.Services)
                {
                    if (service.Uuid.ToString() == serviceUuid)
                    {
                        GattCharacteristicsResult result2 = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);

                        if (result2.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                        {
                            foreach (var characteristic in result2.Characteristics)
                            {
                                if (characteristic.Uuid.ToString() == characteristicUuid)
                                {
                                    var result = await characteristic.ReadValueAsync();

                                    if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                                    {
                                        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(result.Value);
                                        byte[] contents = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                                        reader.ReadBytes(contents);

                                        return contents;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        throw new Exception("Read: Cannot read characteristic:  " + characteristic + " " + Enum.GetName(typeof(GattCommunicationStatus), result.Status));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
// This exception is thrown
                            throw new Exception("Read: Cannot get characteristics for service: " + service.Uuid + " " + Enum.GetName(typeof(GattCommunicationStatus), result2.Status));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            bluetoothLEDevice.Dispose();

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @Odinodin No, I didn’t find the solution to this problem, but I’ve seen somewhere on SO that storing characteristics globally instead of calling GetCharacteristics each time helps… I haven’t tried it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispose of the Gatt services when you're done with them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Whatever, SO. It is a simple answer that can not be expanded. Just dispose of GattServices when you're done with them. if you're coding BLE for Windows you know what the answer means.